# How to make actions by GET request instead of POST request in Vimeo API?

Tags: post, methods, get, vimeo-api

Can I make any action like post comment, upload video, etc.. by send a GET Request instead of POST in Vimeo API? like graph facebook api, can post an comment by GET Request with method parameter

Comment: You can't unless the API allows it.  Some code is written to allow both CGI variables and form-data, some is not.  Try contacting Vimeo and asking them to support CGI. Or are you asking how to add CGI variables to an URL?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't. Our API is RESTful and does not allow this type of behavior. If we document an endpoint, like uploading a video, as POST, you can only do that with a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Likely not in the vein of StackOverflow, but this post is oddly relevant here. 
https://twitter.com/rombulow/status/990684453734203392?lang=en

In sum: GET requests should be idempotent by definition. By defining a GET request to perform some action on the backend, you may run into issues with browsers that preload content based on page links. A sample manifestation of this would be a garage door opening whenever one opens a particular tab in Google Chrome.

Would not recommend ever having a GET perform an action on the BE.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It's not a good idea to use links as answers because SO questions are meant to be useful for years, not just for the person asking them.   A year from now that Twitter account might not exist.  To be more clear, your answer must stand fully on its own, and the link should just be there to give proper credit to your source and for adding information beyond what's needed for the answer.  Right now your answer depends on the link content.